# Secure Compare of Strings in Go

Tags: go

Is the a built-in way of doing constant time string comparison in Go?

I've used the [`Devise.secure_compare`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/7d114271164c7ae39801b07b620d4eddf429a96a/lib/devise.rb#L476-L485) method when I've needed this functionality in Ruby.

Comment: secure_compare is not a constant time method, it calls each_byte, which iterates over every byte in the string

http://apidock.com/ruby/String/each_byte

Comment: "constant time" and "secure" are very different goals; please clarify what exactly you want

Comment: @SethHoenig It is in context of timing attacks. Constant time comparison is not related to time complexity and only means that the comparison function does not return early when a difference is found (which would leak information of how much the inputs differ). The comparison function then depends only on the length of the inputs, not on the contents.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Not for strings but for `[]byte`. See [`crypto/subtle`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/subtle/), especially [`ConstantTimeCompare`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/subtle/#ConstantTimeCompare):

> `func ConstantTimeCompare(x, y []byte) int`
>
> ConstantTimeCompare returns 1 iff the two equal length slices, x and y, have equal contents. The time taken is a function of the length of the slices and is independent of the contents.

As you may know, you can easily convert a string to a byte slice:

```
var x []byte = []byte("someString")
```

Comment: It's also important to use `subtle.ConstantTimeEq` to compare the lengths of the slices due to the caveat that `subtle.ConstantTimeCompare` needs "two equal length slices". It has some "subtle" behaviour otherwise. Example: http://play.golang.org/p/Xga-wsZvhT

Comment: In the [example](http://play.golang.org/p/Xga-wsZvhT) above, the behavior seems correct. Slices that are not of equal length are not equal.

Comment: It isn't really constant time compare then is it? A timing attack would be possible to work out the correct length.

Comment: @MichaelBaldry the function returns false in constant time when the arrays are not of equal length and returns true in (a different) constant time when the arrays are of equal length. So the function does not leak information about the correctness of the contents by timing.

Comment: No doesn't leak the contents, just the length

Comment: @MichaelBaldry OK, yes, this is what @Intermernet meant with "subtle" behavior when using `ConstantTimeCompare` without checking the length first with `ConstantTimeEq`.

Comment: Isn't `[]byte([of a string])` a non-constant time operation though, since "casting" a string to a byte array makes a copy? Seems like that'd leak the length of the expected string.

Comment: @JohnGibb Yes, if you do the conversion in the same request as the comparison then you would leak information. You don't if you hold the converted byte array in memory.

Comment: @JohnGibb If you're checking e.g. a user password, you should use hashes anyway. If you're comparing e.g. an API key, then it should be long enough so that leaking just the length does not matter. (E.g. does it help an attacker to know that a fully random secret is 128 chars? Not much I think)